# How to keep a variable and use the result in another node?

Tags: xml, xslt

Need a help w/ the following:
Has a XML with this:

```
<group>
 <S9>
  <ByAddress>
   <Receipts>
    <ID>10</ID>
    <PaymentAmt>232.23</PaymentAmt>
    <Tax>0.16</Tax>
   </Receipts>
   <Receipts>
     <ID>20</RecID>
     <PaymentAmt>232.23</PaymentAmt>
     <Tax>0.16</Tax>
   </Receipts>
   <Receipts>
     <ID>30</RecID>
     <PaymentAmt>109.04</PaymentAmt>
     <Tax>0.16</Tax>
   </Receipts>
   <Receipts>
     <ID>40</RecID>
     <PaymentAmt>232.23</PaymentAmt>
     <Tax>0.16</Tax>
   </Receipts>
  </ByAddress>
 </S9>
</group>
```

In the current XSL I can convert using only
`format-number(Sum(group/S9/ByAddress/Receipts/PaymentAmt div (1 + group/S9/ByAddress/Receipts/Tax)),'0.00')` in order to have it as NET Amount, besides the Gross Amount (as PaymentAmt) for each line, since the final XML needs to print both by Line a Total Amount. So, each line has the `format-number(PaymentAmt div (1 + Tax),'0.00')`. The issue is generated as a rounding issue since the target system is calculating the Total by line. In this sample:

```
> Line1 200.20
> Line2  94.00
> Line3 200.20
> Line4 200.20
> Total 694.60
```

But the Total by the formula in the schema is  694.59 (0.01 dif) - while the calculation is not printed the results ends with all decimals precision (694.594827) and results always in 0.01 to 0.03 UP/DOWN (for multiple cases).

Question: Is it possible to keep the results from the lines (used in the for-each node) or add those results in a Totalization?
XSLT is somehow this for lines:

```
<Items>
 <xsl:for-each select="Group/S9/ByAddress/Receipts">
  <xsl:attribute name="TaxableAmt">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(abs((PaymentAmt div (1 + Tax))),'0.00')"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="TaxRate">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(abs(Tax),'0.00')"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="TaxAmt">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(abs((PaymentAmt * (Tax))),'0.00')"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:for-each>
</Items>
Total -->
<Total>
  <Taxes>
   <xsl:attribute name="TaxableAmt">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(abs(sum(group/S9/ByAddress/Receipts/PaymentAmt) div (1 + group/S9/ByAddress/Receipts/Tax))),'0.00')"></xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="TaxRate">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(abs(group/S9/ByAddress/Receipts/Tax),'0.00')"></xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="TaxAmt">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(abs(sum(PaymentAmt * (Tax))),'0.00')"></xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:attribute>
  </Taxes>
 </Total>
```

Comment: Please edit your question so it is readable.

Comment: This is not only unreadable, it also makes no sense. Is `PaymentAmt` the net amount or the gross amount? If it's the net amount, why are you dividing it by `(1 + Tax)`?  If it's the gross amount, why are you multiplying it by `Tax`? Also, your title says "keep a variable" - but there is no variable in your code. -- In general, if you want to round individual values AND have a total of the rounded amounts, you would use a variable to calculate the rounded amounts, then output the contents of the variable, followed by the sum of the rounded amounts in the variable.

Comment: Sorry about that! It was a weird message format.
My issue is about the Gross Amount that I need to convert to NET amount ($ - Tax). This is why 232.23 divided by (1 + Tax or 1.16) is 200.20 by line or 200.19828 w/ decimals precision. 
So, when I just use the formula as Sum the Amount, I have this 0.01 to 0.03 cents up or down as difference comparing the result by line vs the calculation by Total.

Comment: I did some minor format updates but the "xslt" is not really valid as it stands currently here

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss, it is not, the real xslt is too big to past here, so I was trying to edit and use only a piece of if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following simplified example:

**XML (corrected to be well-formed!!)**

```
<group>
  <S9>
   <ByAddress>
    <Receipts>
      <ID>10</ID>
      <PaymentAmt>232.23</PaymentAmt>
      <Tax>0.16</Tax>
    </Receipts>
    <Receipts>
      <ID>20</ID>
      <PaymentAmt>232.23</PaymentAmt>
      <Tax>0.16</Tax>
    </Receipts>
    <Receipts>
      <ID>30</ID>
      <PaymentAmt>109.04</PaymentAmt>
      <Tax>0.16</Tax>
    </Receipts>
    <Receipts>
      <ID>40</ID>
      <PaymentAmt>232.23</PaymentAmt>
      <Tax>0.16</Tax>
    </Receipts>
   </ByAddress>
  </S9>
</group>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/group">
    <xsl:variable name="items">
        <xsl:for-each select="S9/ByAddress/Receipts">
            <xsl:variable name="taxable" select="format-number(PaymentAmt div (1 + Tax), '0.00')" />
            <Item 
                TaxableAmt="{$taxable}"
                TaxRate="{Tax}"
                TaxAmt="{format-number(PaymentAmt - xs:decimal($taxable), '0.00')}"/>
                
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <Output>
        <Items>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$items/Item"/>
        </Items>
        <Total
            TaxableAmt="{format-number(sum($items/Item/@TaxableAmt), '0.00')}"
            TaxAmt="{sum($items/Item/@TaxAmt)}"/>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Output>
   <Items>
      <Item TaxableAmt="200.20" TaxRate="0.16" TaxAmt="32.03"/>
      <Item TaxableAmt="200.20" TaxRate="0.16" TaxAmt="32.03"/>
      <Item TaxableAmt="94.00" TaxRate="0.16" TaxAmt="15.04"/>
      <Item TaxableAmt="200.20" TaxRate="0.16" TaxAmt="32.03"/>
   </Items>
   <Total TaxableAmt="694.60" TaxAmt="111.13"/>
</Output>
```

Comment: One more thing: it probably makes no difference here, but you should be aware that `format-number()`rounds using the *round half to even* method.